# Get field from class using string

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class Class{
    public string First{get;set;}
    public string Second{get;set;}
}
```

This is my simply class. Then I create a list with this class. I want to use my variable string to get field from this class for example:

```
var myRecord = new List<class>();
// add...
string myString = "Second";
var somethinf = myRecord.Where(i => i.myString == something)
```

There is a way to get this field `Second` from `myString`

Comment: This should work: `var somethinf = myRecord.Where(i => ((string)typeof(Class).GetProperty("Second").GetValue(i)) == something);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of reflection to accomplish this:

```
 var somethinf = myRecord.Where(prop => ((string)typeof(Class).GetProperty("Second").GetValue(prop)) == something);
```

Please see this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HPckNC).

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding reflection, a simpler approach might be to just make your class wrap a Dictionary:

```
public class Class
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> _dictionary;

    public Class()
    {
        _dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            { "First", "Foo" },
            { "Second", "Bar" }
        };
    }

    public string this[string key]
    {
        get { return _dictionary[key]; }
        set { _dictionary[key] = value; }
    }
}
```

You could then get the data you need using:

```
var myRecords = new List<Class>();
// ...
string variableString = "Second", valueString = "Foo";
var results = myRecords.Where(x => x[variableString] == valueString);
```